# Shining Force 2: Where am I? What next?

Tags: sega-genesis, shining-force-2

I just loaded up a Shining Force 2 savegame from YEARS ago. The problem is, I have no idea where I am, what I'm supposed to be doing, etc.

Can anybody look at this screenshot (okay, picture of my TV) and tell me what I should do next?

[image: Shining Force 2 screenshot]

I've tried placing myself in the walkthrough [here](http://sf2.shiningforcecentral.com/pages/mainguide.html), but shockingly enough there isn't a "when you have a Gandalf, a Fairy, a Bird, and some kind of monster snail with you next to some trees, then go to xyz town".

So can anybody tell me what's going on or where I should go next? I know I'm passed the chess battle, but that's about all I remember.

Edit: Oh, and I'm near a town that almost blends in with the surrounding trees. I think I might have gone there to fight that secret infinite battle? But now I forget where I was actually supposed to be going!

Comment: Your best bet in this case is to just restart.  If you can't even remember where you were, or what you were doing, then refreshing the story is probably a really good idea.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the reply. That might be what I end up doing. I've just done that SO MANY times, and I remember that this savegame was my attempt at FINALLY finishing the story, haha. Then I moved, forgot about it for several years, and didn't pick it back up until today. I was hoping that thanks to the linear story and how much people love this game, this might be an easy one for people to answer. If not, restarting it is!

Comment: This kind of thing usually happens to me when I drink too much while I play a game. I generally end up having to restart the story mode because I'm completely lost when I load my save game. IMHO Frank's advice is the best in your case.

Comment: @BobR.Shake Hahaha you might be hitting pretty close to home. I might end up restarting it, I just figured I'd throw this out there first, on the off chance that a Shining Force 2 fan feels like reminiscing and helping me get my bearings!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

It turns out I had to take the fairy to the sick dwarf in the dwarf cave, which was just to the East of the town I last saved in, just off the river. In return, the dwarfs gave me a cannon.

Then I went to the town to the North (New Granseal?) and got some dynamite for the cannon. Now the next step is to go to the North Cliffs to blow up another cave entrance, to get to North Parmecia.

This can be found at the bottom of [this](http://sf2.shiningforcecentral.com/pages/mainguide_walkthrough_part2.html) page.

Mods: I'm not sure if I should answer this question or just delete it since it's probably useless to everybody else, so let me know if you want me to delete it!

Comment: who's the Gandalf guy in the picture though? My memory of the game's a bit fuzzy but I don't remember who he is at all. Was he a playable character or just a narrator/mentor figure (like Noah in SF1)?)

Comment: @user13267 That is [Sir Astral](http://shining.wikia.com/wiki/Sir_Astral). He is like a teacher wizard type guy, so yeah, basically Gandalf. You can't play as him though. I haven't played this game in a while again, so I might have to post another "what do I do now" question, haha!

Comment: you should post it; I used to love this game, would love to see more discussion about it

Answer (score -3):

You need to the dwarf cave and have the fairy heal the dwarf. I believe he will give you Dynamite or a cannon to use. Then go back to new Granseal. From there you'll be back on track.